# How do I access gzipped files without creating additional processes?

Tags: perl, gzip

My application reads and writes a lot of medium to large files. I would like to store these in zipped format. Saves diskspace and network time.

One way to do it is with this:

```
sub fopen {
  my $mode = shift;
  my $filename = shift;

  if ($filename =~ /\.gz$/) {
    if ($mode eq "<") {
      open(my $fp, "-|", "/usr/bin/gzcat $filename");
      #my $fp = gzopen($filename, "rb") ;
      return $fp;
    }
    if ($mode eq ">") {
      open(my $fp, "|-", "/usr/bin/gzip > $filename");
      #my $fp = gzopen($filename, "wb") ;
      return $fp;
    }
  } else {
    open(my $fp, $mode, $filename);
    return $fp;
  }
}
```

I can then change my existing code simply by swapping the calls to open.

As is apparent from the function, I've also thought of using the zlib/compress library. The problem is that the result can't be passed around as a file pointer.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involved creating a bunch of extra processes?

Comment: Extra processes CAN be useful. If your perl process does a lot of work and you have multiple processors you might get better performance by having a seperate process (on 1 CPU) dedicated to the zip/unzip and then a whole process (on a 2nd CPU) dedicated to your perl program.

Comment: The computer’s **job** is to run processes for you.  Eschew them not.

Answer (score 12):

From the documentation of [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html)

```
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw($GunzipError);

my $z = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new( $input )
    or die "IO::Uncompress::Gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";
```

The variable `$z` is now a file handle that you can use as usual.

```
while (<$z>) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some information about previous answers, from an [old bench I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533067/what-is-the-best-way-to-gunzip-files-with-perl/1539271#1539271), [PerlIO::gzip](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::gzip) is faster than [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Uncompress::Gunzip).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the IO::* namespace on your Perl version.

For example Debian old-stable (5 - Lenny) Perl and next versions, ships [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html) and [IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/AnyUncompress.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);

my $input = "file1.txt.gz";
my $output = "file1.txt";

gunzip $input => $output
    or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";
```