# gunzip or system gzip in perl

Tags: perl, gzip

I wanted to gunzip a file. I want to know whether the gunzip command that comes with perl or the system (uncompress -f  file_name.Z) is more faster or better.

I have included in my perl script

```
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError) ;
```

I wanted to test the gunzip command and so far I have been using uncompress within a system command as:

```
system "wget ${my_file}.Z "
system "uncompress -f ${my_file}.Z";
```

can I also use instead as:

```
gunzip -f ${my_file}.Z
```

without any other overhead involved ?

Comment: You can take a look at [my previous question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1533067/24820)

Answer (score 3):

Z and GZ files use different compression algorithms. GZ was created because Z uses an LZW compression algorithm, which was patented. The patents have since expired, but the two are still incompatible.

Comment: @Yacob, technically, that's a program that you're executing on the system; Perl is only tangentially related. And no, it won't work. You have to use `uncompress` for .z files and `gunzip` for .gz files.